# Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>: Redux with NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I am building my first Next.js site with Redux and I am running into a problem with the error:

> Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the
> component is wrapped in a

I am using `_document.js` to create 'template' for my site, which includes a header and footer:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { PublicHeader, Footer } from '../components';

class Public extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossOrigin />
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700&family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>


            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
            <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/aa1831f3ef.js" crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <PublicHeader />
          <Main />
          <Footer />
          <NextScript>
              <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
          </NextScript>
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default Public
```

I have Redux set up with a store and then I wrapped the `_app.js` with the Provider.

```
import '../styles/css/main.css';
import { useStore } from '../redux/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const store = useStore(pageProps.initialReduxState)
  const persistor = persistStore(store, {}, function () {
    persistor.persist()
  })

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={<div>loading</div>} persistor={persistor}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

All works fine inside the pages but when I try to use `useDispatch` or `useSelector`, I get the error. I am assuming it is because the `_document` is above the `_app` so it can wrap the template around it, but how can I make the store and dispatch available to the `_document`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add React components in `_document` - that should be done in `_app` instead.

From the [Custom `Document`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#caveats) documentation:

> - `Document` is only rendered in the server, event handlers like `onClick` won't work.
> - React components outside of `<Main />` will not be initialized by the browser. Do not add application logic here or custom CSS (like
>   `styled-jsx`). If you need shared components in all your pages (like a
>   menu or a toolbar), take a look at the [`App`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) component instead.

The solution is to move `PublicHeader` and `Footer` to your custom `_app`, so they get initialised properly and have access to the Redux store.

```js
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
    // Remaining code

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={<div>loading</div>} persistor={persistor}>
                <PublicHeader />
                <Component {...pageProps} />
                <Footer />
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! That seems to work! I am still learning how _document.js works in the who scheme of things!

Answer (score 0):

When using workspaces make sure to have both `@reduxjs/toolkit` and `react-redux` installed in the workspace root node_modules folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).